# How to get a levels in mlm 1x3 matrix in php?

Tags: php

In a mlm 1x3 matrix. We have created a tree structure, counting of a nodes like left, middle, right but we have a problem to get a levels of a nodes. If we add a left child, middle child and right child, its successfully added, but i have not get a level of each node.... please help this problem. how to get a levels of a nodes in php.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I don't know how you implemented the tree, but I'm providing suggestions.

You may transverse the tree until the node is found (potentially slow) or, if you're using OOP and each Node is an object, you may solve the problem adding a property for the node level that is updated when is added as child.

```
<?php

class Node
{
    private $children = array();
    private $level = 0;
    private $content;

    public function __construct($content, Node $parent = null)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
        if ($parent) {
            $parent->children[] = $this;
            $this->level = $parent->level + 1;
        }
    }

    public function __get($property)
    {
        return $this->$property;
    }
}

// TEST
$root = new Node('Root');
$a = new Node('A', $root);
$b = new Node('B', $root);
$aa = new Node('AA', $a);
$ab = new Node('AB', $a);

echo $root->content, ' ', $root->level, "\n";
echo $a->content, ' ', $a->level, "\n";
echo $b->content, ' ', $b->level, "\n";
echo $aa->content, ' ', $aa->level, "\n";
echo $ab->content, ' ', $ab->level, "\n";

echo $root->getContent(), ' ', $root->getLevel(), "\n";
echo $a->getContent(), ' ', $a->getLevel(), "\n";
echo $b->getContent(), ' ', $b->getLevel(), "\n";
echo $aa->getContent(), ' ', $aa->getLevel(), "\n";
echo $ab->getContent(), ' ', $ab->getLevel(), "\n";
```

Output:

```
Root 0
A 1
B 1
AA 2
AB 2
```

Remember:

> Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that
>   defines the member.

An object may access private properties of different objects if they're from the same class.